# ¿como puedo hacer un TRIGGER con update y after, usando 2 tablas distintas?

Tags: mysql, xampp, trigger, update, localhost

Hola necesito saber como hacer un TRIGGER con update y afther usando 2 tablas distintas.

tengo la tabla calificaciones y la tabla alumno.

la tabla calificaciones tiene como campos: **idalumno, materia1, materia2, materia3, materia4, materia5, materia6 y materia7**. Y la tabla alumnos solo tiene **idalumno y promgral** (promedio geneal).

como le hago para hacer un TRIGGER que cuando el se actualice un dato de alguna columna de materia en calificaciones, se haga un promedio de las calificaciones y se almacene en **promgral**

`UPDATE alumnos SET alumnos.promgral=(SUM( NEW.materia1 + NEW.materia2 + NEW.materia3 + NEW.materia4 + NEW.materia5 + NEW.materia6 + NEW.materia7)/7) WHERE alumnos.idalumno=calificaciones.idalumno`

asta ahorita llevo esto pero no me sale, al modificar una calificacion me sale **#1054 - La columna 'calificaciones.idalumno' en where clause es desconocida**

Me podrían decir como hacerle, ya le intente de todo (cambiar de new a old, cambiar el nombre de la tabla, pornerle join y inner join, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas un trigger puedes buscar los valores que permanecen con la instrucción `old` por lo que al actualizar tu tabla en este caso puedes obtener el id como `old.idalumno` quedando tu consulta:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_calificaciones_update
AFTER UPDATE ON calificaciones FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE alumnos SET alumnos.promgral=(SUM(NEW.materia1 + NEW.materia2 + 
    NEW.materia3 + NEW.materia4 + NEW.materia5 + NEW.materia6 + NEW.materia7)/7) 
    WHERE alumnos.idalumno=old.idalumno
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```